# Capture the output of a QR scanner from a raspberry in C++

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, qr-code, raspbian

I have a QR scanner attached to my raspberry pi 3 B+. I need to capture the output of the scanner from C++ on raspbian. The scanner writes the read information to the window with the focus, like a keyboard input.

I have tried to capture the keyboard input with the ncurses library and other similar choices but sometimes I get an incomplete code, because I don't know when the read info ends, and I don't know when I have a complete input.

I tried something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    char buffer[1000];
    while (true) {
        getstr(buffer);
        cout<< buffer << endl;
        napms(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I may get the code in a fragmented way if it's too long or if the output slows down for whatever reason.

Comment: Looks like you have two problems here. Reduce the question to one problem and greatly expand on it.Cite research and provide code so we know how far you have gotten and from that a better idea of how best to help you.

Comment: Maybe tell us the make and model of the scanner and/or how it is attached. How do you start scanning?

Comment: I really have just one problem: how to capture the output of the keyboard when the sequence of characters is obtained from the QR scanner. I think that the brand and the model of the scanner are irrelevant, since the output is sent as keyboard entry.